# Swashbuckle SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults attribute still adding 200 Success response to Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-core-3.1, swagger-3.0

I'm using Swashbuckle and Swagger UI in a .NET Core 3.1 project, with my XML comments imported into Swagger. I have a POST request on a controller that I want to register a number of response statuses (201, 401, 403, 404) for in Swagger. The problem is that I'm also seeing a *200 Success* response listed alongside my explicitly specified status code responses in the `swagger.json` file and the Swagger UI interface.

As suggested in multiple different places I'm using the `[SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]` attribute to try and prevent this, however everything I try still results in the default 200 response being listed.

I've tried:

- adding the attribute to the method,
- adding the attribute to the controller,
- adding the attribute to the abstract base controller,

and all combinations of the above. I've also tried these in combination with:

- specifying desired response types with XML `<response code="XXX"></response>` comment tags, and
- specifying desired response types with `[SwaggerResponse(XXX)]` endpoints.

Nothing results in the removal of the *200 Success* result from my Swagger UI and `swagger.json`.

**TrackerController.cs**

```
/// <summary>...</summary>
/// <response code="401">User is not authenticated.</response>
/// <response code="404">Tracker not found.</response>
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]
public partial class TrackersController : AbstractController
{
    ...

    /// <summary>...</summary>
    /// <param name="tracker">The details of the tracker to be created.</param>
    /// <response code="201">The tracker was successfully created.</response>
    /// <response code="403">User is not authorized to modify this resource.</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]
    [ResponseType(typeof(TrackerDto))]
    [SwaggerResponse(201, Description = "The tracker was successfully created.")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTracker([FromBody] TrackerDto tracker)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

**swagger.json**

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "My API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/Trackers": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Trackers"
        ],
        "summary": "Create a new tracker.",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "The details of the tracker to be created.",
          "content": {
            "application/json-patch+json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TrackerDto"
              }
            },
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TrackerDto"
              }
            },
            "text/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TrackerDto"
              }
            },
            "application/*+json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TrackerDto"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          },
          "201": {
            "description": "The tracker was successfully created."
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "User is not authenticated."
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "User is not authorized to modify this resource."
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Tracker not found."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Swagger UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT5Up.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are telling Swagger you are producing a `TrackerDto` with the default type of 200 **and in addition** another response of 201. You need to make that *one single* matching pair.

Drop the `ResponseType` attribute and put the type where it belongs:

```
[SwaggerResponse(201, Description = "The tracker was successfully created.", typeof(TrackerDto))]
```

You could also try:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(TrackerDto), 201)]
```

The important thing is to put the type and the status code in the same attribute so Swagger knows they belong together.

Comment: Tried this and this didn't solve it either - I've got another test controller method that is stripped down to the simplest possible scenario: with no abstract base controller, no `[Authorize]` attributes, only XML comment `<response code="XXX"></response>` tags for response types and the `[SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]` attribute still doesn't remove the *200 Success* response.

Comment: Can you try to drop *everything*, all other attributes and comments (except for maybe the HTTP verb and AllowAnonymous) and just use one of the options in the answer please?

Comment: For some reason `SwaggerResponse` attributes aren't being picked up by Swashbuckle for me, but I can confirm that the `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(TrackerDto), 201)]` approach does remove the default *200 Success* response from the list. To add a description for the response types I'm just using XML comment docs as well and it's linking the two together.